# How do I keep the publisher from being stripped from fpassthru exes files?

Tags: php

I am creating a simple proxy downloader that just passes the file stream through the server.  It seems to work with most files alright, but exe seems to have a problem in that the 'publisher' is some how stripped.

```
$url = "http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe"
$bname = basename($url);
$ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
header('Content-type: application/'.$ext);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$bname.'"');
fpassthru(fopen($url, 'rb'));
```

I've tried using different header information for exes:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
```

This does not make a difference.  In both cases, the exe files is downloaded, and it can be run but windows 8 complains about it having an 'unknown' publisher.  This does not happen when downloading the exe directly.  It seems like I am just about there, but something is slightly off.  In what step is the exe being modified (the reading or the output)?  How do I do this properly?  Thank you!

Comment: `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is a MIME (email) header. Why people add it to their HTTP headers is beyond me. It has no place there.

Comment: You could use `curl` and get all the headers from the original server, and resend them in your response. But none of them look like they'd be related to this.

Comment: Why not using [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mime-content-type.php) (deprecated though), which gives an alternative `application/x-msdownload`, although this is a guess and just a code reduction.

Comment: All of these comments so far are related to the content headers.  I take this to mean you believe it is the content headers that are causing the difference in the downloaded exe?